# Can a List<type> have names or is there a way to have a "flexible" property?

Tags: c#, list, properties, tuples

I am working in 3D space (X, Y, Z).

I have a KDTree (thanks to [Accord.Net](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Collections_KDTree_1.htm)) that I am inheriting and adding a property that has the max and min of each dimension. I wrote a constructor that adds values from a list and gets the min and max at the same time.

The tree (in my case) can be 1, 2 or 3 dimensions.

I would like to have a property that looks like this if the tree has one dimension (X axis):

```
Tree.MinMax.X.Min
Tree.MinMax.X.Min
```

If my tree has two dimensions (Say Y and Z) then the property would look like this:

```
Tree.MinMax.Y.Min
Tree.MinMax.Y.Min
Tree.MinMax.Z.Min
Tree.MinMax.Z.Min
```

What I currently have is a list. There is no way to name each item in the list (that I know of).

```
class MinMax
{
    internal double Min = double.MaxValue;
    internal double Max = double.MinValue;

    internal void Add(double value)
    {
        Min = msf.Min(Min, value);
        Max = msf.Max(Max, value);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following syntax (which is hard to follow):

```
Tree.MinMax[0].Min
Tree.MinMax[0].Max
```

Is there a way to name list elements or a way to make a property that is "flexible, kind of like a named tuple?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get this right... but you maybe want a [`Dictionary<string, MinMax>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tree.MinMax` can be a [`Dictionary<string, MinMax>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
public Dictionary<string, MinMax> MinMax = new Dictionary<string, MinMax>();
```

To add a key value pair (or in your words, a "flexible property"),

```
MinMax.Add("Y", new MinMax());
```

Then you can access the property like this:

```
MinMax["Y"]
```

This will throw a `KeyNotFoundException` if the key does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation and clear example. I did not realize that I could access dictionary keys using ["X"].

Comment: @EricSnyder Is there something else you'd like to ask about this? If not, why did you unaccept?

Comment: Just trying it out in VS. I am finding that I can also use a SortedList<string, MinMax> in the same way. I can also define a constant const string X = "X"; and then use SortedList[X].Amethod(); I like your solution,i'd kind of like to play with this some more and also wait and see if other solutions come along as well.

Comment: good solution, it is working well, especially with the constants defined.